# How to have a Custom Datagrid control with fixed columns whose width is adjustable?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datagrid, dependency-properties

What i am trying to do is make a CustomDatagrid which has already 2 fixed columns. Then i can re-use this CustomDatagrid and add extra columns to fit my best purpose. But when i do add extra columns i would like to be able to resize the 2 fixed columns. I tried working it out with dependency properties as the example underneath but to no avail. And i do not get any binding errors whatsoever which leaves me without any idea what is wrong.

=> this small example will clarify what i am trying to do

CustomDataGrid.Xaml

```
<DataGrid x:Class="DataGridWidthTestControl.CustomDataGrid"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:DataGridWidthTestControl"
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">
<DataGrid.Columns>
    <DataGridTextColumn Width="{Binding Column1Width}" Header="Column1"/>
    <DataGridTextColumn Width="{Binding Column2Width}" Header="Column2"/>
</DataGrid.Columns>
```

CustomDataGrid.Xaml.CS - Codebehind

```
namespace DataGridWidthTestControl
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for CustomDataGrid.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class CustomDataGrid : DataGrid
    {
        public CustomDataGrid()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            DataContext = this;
        }

        public static readonly DependencyProperty Column1WidthProperty = DependencyProperty.Register( "Column1Width", typeof(DataGridLength), typeof(CustomDataGrid), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(new DataGridLength(25, DataGridLengthUnitType.Star)));

        public DataGridLength Column1Width
        {
            get { return (DataGridLength)GetValue(Column1WidthProperty); }
            set { SetValue(Column1WidthProperty, value); }
        }

        public static readonly DependencyProperty Column2WidthProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("Column2Width", typeof(DataGridLength), typeof(CustomDataGrid), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(new DataGridLength(15, DataGridLengthUnitType.Star)));

        public DataGridLength Column2Width
        {
            get { return (DataGridLength)GetValue(Column2WidthProperty); }
            set { SetValue(Column2WidthProperty, value); }
        }

    }
}
```

Mainwindow.xaml (codebehind is empty except for default initialize call)

```
<Window x:Class="DataGridWidthTestControl.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:DataGridWidthTestControl"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <local:CustomDataGrid Column1Width="1*" Column2Width="1*" >
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn Width="10*" Header="column3"/>
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </local:CustomDataGrid>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you need to know that bindings without any source specified (like in your case), bindings using `Binding.RelativeSource` and bindings using `Binding.ElementName` will not work with `DataGridColumn`, because it derives directly from `DependencyObject`, which is not sufficient. Basically, in order for those to work, the target object needs to be of type deriving from `FrameworkElement` or `FrameworkContentElement`, and it should be part of the visual or logical tree (which `DataGridColumn`s are not). Be aware though that there are few exceptions to that requirement (like `Freezable`s defined within resource dictionaries), and more to come with upcoming versions of the framework.

So unfortunately you need to explicitly specify `Binding.Source` (which should be an instance of your `CustomDataGrid` class). I can't think of any way of doing it in *XAML* (`Source={x:Reference (...)}` is not applicable because you cannot reference an object from within its definition), so I think you'll need to fallback to code-behind (which is not unusual when devising custom controls).

The easiest way is to name your columns:

```
<DataGrid.Columns>
    <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="Column1" x:FieldModifier="private" Header="Column1" />
    <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="Column2" x:FieldModifier="private" Header="Column2" />
</DataGrid.Columns>
```

(`x:FieldModifier="private"` is optional) and then set the bindings upon initialization of your control:

```
public CustomDataGrid()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    BindingOperations.SetBinding(Column1, DataGridColumn.WidthProperty, new Binding
    {
        Path = new PropertyPath(Column1WidthProperty),
        Source = this,
    });
    BindingOperations.SetBinding(Column2, DataGridColumn.WidthProperty, new Binding
    {
        Path = new PropertyPath(Column2WidthProperty),
        Source = this,
    });
}
```

You also may want to add `Mode = BindingMode.TwoWay` to the bindings so that the values on your control stay in sync if the user resizes the columns manually.

Note that I intentionally removed the `DataContext = this` line because **a)** it is not necessary and **b)** it would give you a lot of trouble when using your control (e.g. binding `DataGrid.ItemsSource` to a view-model property would not work as it usually does).

Comment: This fits my needs very well! I only added the "DataContext = this" to clarify the example anyway :)

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to programmatically insert the fixed columns in your CustomDataGrid class instead of specifying them in the template.

Something like:

```
public override void OnApplyTemplate()
{
    if (!this.Columns.Any(c => c.Header.ToString() == "Column1"))
    {
        this.Columns.Insert(0,
                            new DataGridTextColumn
                            {
                                Width = this.Column1Width,
                                Header = "Column1"
                            });
    }

    if (!this.Columns.Any(c => c.Header.ToString() == "Column2"))
    {
        this.Columns.Insert(1,
                            new DataGridTextColumn
                            {
                                Width = this.Column2Width,
                                Header = "Column2"
                            });
    }

    base.OnApplyTemplate();
}
```

I'm not sure OnApplyTemplate() is the right time to do it, there might be a better method to override, but this is the concept I'd go for to make this work.